# how to use the microSD adapter?

Tags: gpio, sd-card

i connected sd card at the bottom of raspberry pi 3. But there is no place to put sd adapter?
what is it and what it does? Sdcard has a memory of 16G, and i was able to coonect it, bottom of the pi. 
In case of urgency, how can I shutdown the pi in case of kernel panic, like with PCs.

Comment: What does this have to do with GPIO?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean something that looks like this [image: micro SD card adapter top and micro SD card bottom]. The top item is a micro SD card adapter, and it is used to allow reading and writing of the micro SD card in a computer with only a standard SD card slot. It is not needed by the Pi 3, since the Pi is designed to use a micro SD card.

If the Pi has a kernel panic your only option to shut down may be to pull the power.